# "Сильная" атака

Tags: лексика

Каким прилагательным можно характеризовать действие типа стук, столкновение, удар (будь то удар рукой, пальцем о клавишу рояля или ложкой по тарелке), характеризующееся быстрым и сильным исполнением, иногда с небольшим размахом. Цепкий, крепкий, прочный?

Comment: Очень странно — Вам четыре участника месяц назад предоставили энное количество прилагательных. Неужели ни одно из них Вас не устроило?! Ребята думали-крутили-искали... Неправильно это. Я поддержу сегодня **всех**.

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом на ум приходит слово "резкий".
В некоторых ситуациях можно также сказать "пронзительный".
А если ложкой о тарелку, то "звонкий".

Answer (score 1):

Чёткий, отточенный, выверенный, лихой.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё так: *отрывистый*. В фортепианной музыке специальный термин: marcato (отчётливо, с ударением). Или, в некоторых случаях, staccato (отрывисто).

Answer (score 1):

Смачный, сочный, залихватский, бойкий, шибкий, верный, размеренный...